# Implementing data driven framework using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to build a datadriven framework using selenium webdriver with java binding. i am bit confused with regards to choosing the right tool for building framework

Could somebody please recommend which framework (i.e. Junit, TestNG, Cucumber) works better with large set of test data

Also, please suggest which data file format i.e. .xls or .tsv to use for executing automated tests from Jenkins(deployed on Linux box)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As fare as I know and what I have earlier used Selenium for is to implement automated test scenarios of a web-application. Would typically be accept-test og end-to-end test (e2e).

These kind of test are what you call Black-Box testing. You give a input and expect a output, but does not know what is going on inside the black-box (you application).

To implement and execute your tests scenarios you would use a test-framework as you also mentioned (JUnit, TestNG, Cucumber etc.).

All test are able to be executed on a build server running Jenkins whether it is unit/integration or e2e-test (which could be implemented with Selenium).

Selenium test are expensive to maintain and often you would run into timing issues which causes test to fail even though the code does not contain any errors.

Therefore it is important to implement the test correct, otherwise you would run into a maintenance hell.

I am not sure if you are new to testing?? Maybe you could benefit from reading a bit about software testing.
The following is a good link: https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/software-testing/

Let me know, if I have misunderstood you question totally :)

Comment: @mskydt87, thanks for your reply, personally I don't have much experience with Jenkins, however somebody mentioned in the past that Jenkins may cause issues with reading test data file in Excel format during the automation execution, it will be really helpful if somebody can share their experience with regards to handling test data file in excel format

Comment: Hi mskydt87, You mentioned that "Selenium test are expensive to maintain and often you would run into timing issues which causes test to fail even though the code does not contain any errors."

I would really apricate, if you could provide some more information about "Timing issues" you mentioned above, what do you mean by timing issue ?

Comment: Hi again,
Selenium is a webdriver used to implement GUI test, for instance if you would like to  automate GUI-test.
I have not heard of these problems with Jenkins.
If you don't have more than one sheet in your Excel file, you could convert it to a comma-separated-file (.csv).
In that way you would not have your test-data in a binary file which is also nice.
It sounds like you just wanna create unit/integration test of your backend. Then then execute those test on a build server with Jenkins.
Am i right?